# React Native Hot Reloading no longer able to reload in simulator

Tags: android, react-native, hot-reload

I'm currently using react native version 0.61.5 and I no longer able to do reload by hitting the R button twice. It's as if no command was being send to the emulator. It's just not able to detect the emulator.

I've tried to update react native to the latest version, 0.63.1 but its just the same. I'm really struggling with this as every time i need to see any reload, i need to build the bundle an reinstall the app, which is taking forever.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: they have changed the way you refresh the simulator. You can press `r` on the terminal to refresh your simulator.

Comment: When i press r, it will say app reloading... then i got a warning saying it cant detect any emulator

Answer (score 0):

So this is what i do, click on emulator and press CTRL + M (CMD + M on MacOS) or shake the Android device which has the running app. Then you should see the reload option there or you can also enable the live reload option.

Comment: when i press the CTRL button, then i got some sort of a 3 circle symbol appeared on the screen but i have no idea what it is for though. Doesn't really reload the app

Comment: Alternatively for Android, you can run the command adb shell input keyevent 82 to open the dev menu (82 being the Menu key code). Reference: https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.59/debugging#:~:text=You%20can%20access%20the%20developer,M%20on%20Windows%20and%20Linux.